# How to update ContentType Label through API chaining?

Tags: api, contact-types, chaining

I try to relabel Organization as "Entity":

```
$result = civicrm_api3('ContactType', 'create', array(
  'label' => "Entity",
  'api.ContactType.get' => array('name' => "Organization"),
));
```

This errors out with

> Mandatory key(s) missing from params array: name, parent_id

Apparently I don't understand chaining and the required 'id' for updating is not returned. What is wrong in my reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got it! I had to think backwards:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('ContactType', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'name' => "Organization",
  'api.ContactType.create' => array('label' => "Entity", 'id' => "\$value.id"),
));
```

Comment: glad you figured it out!